# How to label histogram bars with data values or percents in R

Tags: r, graphics, histogram

I'd like to label each bar of a histogram with either the number of counts in that bin or the percent of total counts that are in that bin. I'm sure there must be a way to do this, but I haven't been able to find it. This page has a couple of pictures of SAS histograms that do basically what I'm trying to do (but the site doesn't seem to have R versions): http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/sas/faq/histogram_anno.htm

If possible, it would also be nice to have the flexibility to put the labels above or somewhere inside the bars, as desired.

I'm trying to do this with the base R plotting facilities, but I'd be interested in methods to do this in ggplot2 and lattice as well.

Comment: Do you want something like this(http://stackoverflow.com/a/9185168/707145)?

Comment: See this one also http://stackoverflow.com/q/6644997/707145

Comment: Yes. That example is a bar plot, but I'm looking to do something similar with a histogram, though I'd like to have fine control over where the text goes, rather than having to put it directly above each bar.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

To include the number of counts, you can just set `labels=TRUE`.

The example below is just slightly adapted from one on the  [`hist()`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/graphics/html/hist.html) help page:

```
hist(islands, col="gray", labels = TRUE, ylim=c(0, 45))
```

[image]

Getting percentages is a bit more involved.  The only way I know to do that it to directly manipulate the object returned by a call to `hist()`, as described in a bit more detail in my answer to [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9080917/histogram-on-lattice/9083916#9083916):

```
histPercent <- function(x, ...) {
   H <- hist(x, plot = FALSE)
   H$density <- with(H, 100 * density* diff(breaks)[1])
   labs <- paste(round(H$density), "%", sep="")
   plot(H, freq = FALSE, labels = labs, ylim=c(0, 1.08*max(H$density)),...)
}

histPercent(islands, col="gray")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Josh. Two follow-ups: (1) What if I want to still plot counts, but label the bars with percents? (2) Is there a way to get fine control over the vertical placement of the numbers (e.g., place them inside the bars (top, middle or bottom), just beneath the bars, etc.? Also, is there a way to control the rotation of the text (e.g., rotate 90 deg so large numbers will still fit).

Comment: @eipi10: See my comments for ggplot2 versions and for more control over the place of counts and percentages.

Comment: @eipi10 -- The second part of my answer should be enough to get you started with finer control, if you really want to do this.  The key bit is that calls to `hist()` return an object which has all of the pieces you need to get the coordinates for labels that you can then place using `text()` or whatever.

Comment: Great answer, thanks! Is it possible to adjust the size of the text on top of the bars? I have tried `cex`, `cex.axis`, `cex.main` and  `cex.sub` but no joy..

Comment: How can we fit a probability distribution to this plot? with *hist* we can simply add density with *lines* to fit the data, here it doesn't work, why?

Answer (score 7):

Adding numbers at the tops of the bars in barplots or histograms distorts the visual interpretation of the bars, even putting the labels inside of the bars near the top creates a fuzzy top effect that makes it harder for the viewer to properly interpret the graph.  If the number are of interest then this creates a poorly laid out table, why not just create a proper table.

If you really feel the need to add the numbers then it is better to put them below the bars or along the top margin so that they line up better for easier comparison and don't interfere with the visual interpretation of the graph.  Labels can be added to base graphs using the `text` or `mtext` functions and the x locations can be found in the return value from the `hist` function.  Heights for plotting can be computed using the `grconvertY` function.

Comment: Thanks Greg. I agree with your comments about text placement. See my comment to Josh's answer regarding fine control of text placement.

Comment: I also find that plotting a grid instead of the value numbers is sufficient to give a fair representations of the real values